# Download an App to Android 4.3 from a Glassfish 4 server

Tags: java, android, servlets, glassfish

Hi I'm trying to install an app using a servlet on glassfish 4 using servlet witht the doGet method displayed below.  This works fine on older versions of Android, but not 4.3 at least not on a Galaxy Nexus. I haven't been able to test it on other phones.

I have set the phone to accept downloads from unknown sources, and the verify apps functionality is also turned off.

When I do the download I get an error dialog on the phone saying that a problem occurred while the packkage was analyzed. This is not surprising, because if I look at the actual downoaded file, it appears to be empty. As far as I can remember this download method worked on Galaxy Nexus before it was upgraded to 4.3.

Are there any changes in the handling of http in Android 4.3 that would account for this behaviour or what is the problem? Any ideas?

```
 @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        int length = 0;
        try (ServletOutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream()) {
            String mimeType = "application/vnd.android.package-archive";
            response.setContentType(mimeType);
            response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
            String fileName = (new File(filePath)).getName();
            response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");

            byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[BUFSIZE];
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);
            try (DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fin)) {
                while ((in != null) && ((length = in.read(byteBuffer)) != -1)) {
                    outStream.write(byteBuffer, 0, length);
                }
            }
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
            fin.close();


        }
    }
```

Comment: What are you using, on the Android side, to make this GET request?

Comment: I have tried Firefox, Chrome, and the old Android web browser all give the same behavior.  Examining the problem a bit further it seams that glassfish crashes when it tries to parse a "Cookie:" header containing an empty string. [link](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20887). I have tried the patch that is suggested in that link but that only gives me an IOException in the serverlog:   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)